# Sync_queue class compilation error

Tags: c++, multithreading

Stroustrup has presented a synchronized queue class [Sync_queue](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/270988c547c79481). (CPL, 4, pp 1232-1235).

The [Sync_queue tester](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f718e94a6171ebde)
gives the following compilation errors:

```
In file included from main.cpp:9:

./Sync_queue.h:69:47: error: variable 'min_size' cannot be implicitly captured in a lambda with no capture-default specified
                    [this] {return q.size() < min_size;});
                                              ^
./Sync_queue.h:62:23: note: 'min_size' declared here
         unsigned int min_size)
                      ^
./Sync_queue.h:69:21: note: lambda expression begins here
                    [this] {return q.size() < min_size;});
                    ^
1 error generated.
```

The relevant portion of the `Sync_queue` class (where the compilation errors occur) is a method containing a lambda, shown below:

```
/** During a duration d, if the queue size
    falls below a minimum level,
    put a value onto the queue. */
template<typename T>
bool Sync_queue<T>::put(
         T val, 
         std::chrono::steady_clock::duration d,
         unsigned int min_size)
{
   std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck {mtx};

   bool low = cnd.wait_for(
                    lck,
                    d,
                    [this] {return q.size() < min_size;});

   if (low)
   {
      q.push_back(val);
      cnd.notify_one();
   }
   else
   {
      cnd.notify_all();
   }

   return low;
}
```

The following line is **line 62**:

```
     unsigned int min_size)
```

and **line 69** contains the lambda as a predicate to the `condition_variable`'s `wait_for()` method:

```
                [this] {return q.size() < min_size;});
```

How do I fix this compilation error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use `min_size` inside a lambda expression you should explicitly capture it:

`[this, min_size] {return q.size() < min_size;}`

Another option would be to use automatic captures like `[&]` or `[=]` but in general it's better to use explicit captures to prevent your lambda from unexpected side effects. 
For detailed explanation see [cppreference on lambdas](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) - *captures* item.